# BluetoothListener.AcceptBluetooth client blocks in 32Feet windows 7

Tags: c#, bluetooth, 32feet

We are creating application to communicat external device with windows PC (here we are using windows 7), in PC we are using bluetooth dongle.

when we tried to discover and pair device it was successfull in windows PC.

But in code side we are trying to connect the device it was not successfull and here we are using 32feet.net to connect the device.

below code i am trying to connect the device.

```
////_serviceClassId = new Guid("9bde4762-89a6-418e-bacf-fcd82f1e0677");
        Guid serviceClass = BluetoothService.RFCommProtocol;
        int selectedIndex = device_list.SelectedIndex;
        BluetoothDeviceInfo selectedDevice = this.array[selectedIndex];
        var lsnr = new BluetoothListener(serviceClass);
        lsnr.Start();
        Task.Run(() => Listener(lsnr));
```

and the Listener method is

```
private void Listener(BluetoothListener lsnr)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                using (var client = lsnr.AcceptBluetoothClient())
                {
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream()))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
                            {
                                ////_responseAction(content);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (IOException)
                        {
                            client.Close();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // todo handle the exception
            // for the sample it will be ignored
        }
    }
```

If i run the application it will blocked in the `lsnr.AcceptBluetoothClient()` Can any one help what wrong in this?

Note : Bluetooth device created two comports one is incoming and anther one is outgoing port, when we connect through PC.

Answer (score 0):

It is because it wait untill it have a client connected. You have to run it in a thread to work simultaneously!